# How can you iterate through dict items at the same time with variable dict length?

Tags: python, pytorch

I want to iterate through a dict that has `n` keys and values.

eg:

```
d = {0:"batched data", 1:"batched data", 2:"batched data", ..., n: "batched data"}
```

Since the batched data is of the pytorch [DataLoader](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html) form, it is not indexable only iterable.

Thus, how can I iterate through all of the dict batched data at once:

I was thinking zip may be useful, but I was unsure how to compute this when the length is variable.

For instance if `n=3`:

```
for index, data in enumerate(zip(d[0],d[1],d[2])):
```

would work, but how can this be generalized for any number of dict elements?

Comment: `for index, data in enumerate(zip(*d))`?

Comment: what type of output you want? please provide code example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the output of your command:

```
for index, data in enumerate(zip(d[0],d[1],d[2])):
    print("{} -> {}".format(index, data))
```

it seems to me that this will handle the generic case:

```
d = {0:"batched data", 1:"batched data", 2:"batched data", 3: "batched data"}

for index, data in enumerate(zip(*d.values())):
    print("{} -> {}".format(index, data))
```

Output:

```
0 -> ('b', 'b', 'b', 'b')
1 -> ('a', 'a', 'a', 'a')
2 -> ('t', 't', 't', 't')
3 -> ('c', 'c', 'c', 'c')
4 -> ('h', 'h', 'h', 'h')
5 -> ('e', 'e', 'e', 'e')
6 -> ('d', 'd', 'd', 'd')
7 -> (' ', ' ', ' ', ' ')
8 -> ('d', 'd', 'd', 'd')
9 -> ('a', 'a', 'a', 'a')
10 -> ('t', 't', 't', 't')
11 -> ('a', 'a', 'a', 'a')
```